# Decrypt TLS record layer using OpenSSL

Tags: tls, openssl, decryption

I am trying to decrypt a given TLS record layer sent by a client using OpenSSL. The TLS version is `TLS 1.2` and the cipher suite is `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`.

The encrypted record layer is given by `16030300400325f41d3ebaf8986da712c82bcd4d5524be34e37fe65ad790c3499facf551714ffb066152448c8a185060c9ff09345c467850c85e299b8547cf1038ae3f1033` and was created by the MAC-then-PAD-then-ENCRYPT scheme. Hence, the first bytes correspond to the content type (16), the version (0303) and the length (0040), i.e. the actual encrypted message is given by `0325f41d3ebaf8986da712c82bcd4d5524be34e37fe65ad790c3499facf551714ffb066152448c8a185060c9ff09345c467850c85e299b8547cf1038ae3f1033`.

In addition to that, I am given the key block `06 19 3E FB A9 03 A7 68 AB 43 22 F4 1B B1 40 E8 C0 F3 13 44 0A F8 13 1A 39 DC 43 9C 5A D1 B8 B0 D3 AA DA D6 AA 45 5B C8 2F 1B 9D 51 FD B2 69 CF C5 5A 3A 37 15 31 D4 52 AA BF 9A 20 82 16 FB 73 7E 09 C7 9E 86 0C D5 07 F5 F8 6F 5C FB 31 DE 16 93 65 ED 49 84 30 C3 FC D0 5C 6B 49 C6 04 F1 DA F6 EA BF CB FC 23 F6 21`, which was created by a key derivation procedure.

Since AES-256-CBC is used for encryption, the initialization vector has a length of 16 bytes, the key material has a length of 32 bytes and the MAC has a length of 20 bytes according to [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) (page 83). Hence, I can extract the client_write_key from the given key_block, which is `2f1b9d51fdb269cfc55a3a371531d452aabf9a208216fb737e09c79e860cd507` and the IV from the record layer, which is `0325f41d3ebaf8986da712c82bcd4d55`. (The client_wirte_key can be used for encryption and decryption of messages sent by the client, right?)

Now I am trying to use OpenSSL to decrypt the message with the following command:

`openssl enc -nopad -d -aes-256-cbc -iv 0325f41d3ebaf8986da712c82bcd4d55 -K 2f1b9d51fdb269cfc55a3a371531d452aabf9a208216fb737e09c79e860cd507 -in content.txt`

where content.txt only contains the actual encrypted message. However, this seems not to be the correct method, because all I get is some unreadable byte code. At this point, I have to idea, what I might have done wrong. Or is there some problem with my understanding of how the record layer encryption/decryption and the correct usage of the keys?

I would be very grateful, if someone could help me finding my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess -- this is the first message sent by the client after CCS (Change Cipher Spec)? Note type 0x16 is handshake, not application data. And the result I get from decrypting is

```
00000000: 1400 000c 85a0 32d7 cb3a c5af 177e 11ce  ......2..:...~..
00000010: 96e6 4e87 524f 1ef3 5d3b d7c0 03fc bd82  ..N.RO..];......
00000020: b3fd 3627 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b  ..6'............
```

which is the correctly HMAC-SHA1ed (with pseudoheader 0000000000000000 1603030010) and TLS-padded version of the following handshake message:

```
00000000: 1400 000c 85a0 32d7 cb3a c5af 177e 11ce  ......2..:...~..
```

which is a correctly-formatted Finished (see 5246 section 7.9) which is the first message (and record) that must be sent encrypted after CCS. (Your given data is insufficient to determine if it is *fully* correct, i.e. the value in it verifies the handshake.)